# Universal web-safe fonts

Tags: android, css, text, fonts, transform

Old issue. I can't get over the fact that Chrome and Firefox under Android 7.0 fail to correctly display text having this styling:

```
.st8{font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:19px;}
```

for an SVG element having text tag `<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 61.6089 161.1328)" class="st8">Водород</text>`. 
[The page](http://chemistrytable.scienceontheweb.net/index_eng_svg.php) I'm working with. The text "Водород" on Android gets converted to Arial, I guess. Not Times New Roman.

Despite the font being web-safe. 
I need the font to be exactly the same on various platforms. Otherwise, if it reverts to some Arial, the layout looks assymetrical. 
Another font Georgia, for some reason renders just about fine on Android.
Any suggestions?

After edit.
As I see it, if [w3](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html) and [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) present a list of the most common web-safe fonts, then it has to be working no matter the browser. Well, I wish it. Why would then w3schools teach or show standards which are not adopted by everybody?

To me, it would make more sense if Google expanded its collection of fonts with 5 most common Windows/Apple fonts and added those to its Android system. Would be fair. A pareto-optimal exchange.

Google easily takes advantage of proprietory Arial font (read Windows-based font) in its Google docs apps, but fails to integrate Windows based fonts in its Android system. Wiki article on Arial font - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial

Answer (score 0):

Try using: [fonts.google.com](http://fonts.google.com)

The most popular fonts (Open Sans, Roboto, Montserrat, etc.) usually have multiple language support.

Comment: Thanks. Been there. Made a gruesome discovery that there is a price tag attached to Times New Roman. 
Looking for a serif font that has finishing curves, like Times New Roman.